# How do I make this use the same button for open and close

Tags: javascript

So I'm using the following script; which opens and closes a side bar.

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is instead of having two buttons like;

```
<a href="#" onclick="openNav()">Open</a>

<a href="#" onclick="closeNav()">Close</a>
```

Is to have one button that performs both actions like the first time its clicked opens the side bar and the second time it gets clicked the side bar closes.

Comment: Check if the style width is greater than 0, if it is, open. Otherwise, close.

Comment: Are you aware of the if else statements? If not. I will highly recommend you learning at least core Javascript

Comment: @user1533609 I'm new to javascript just made this and then got stuck at this

Comment: no px needed in js 250 not 250px

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then have one button:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleNav()">Toggle</a>
```

And in the function determine which action to take:

```
function toggleNav() {
    var element = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
    if (element.style.width == "250px") {
        element.style.width = "0px";
    } else {
        element.style.width = "250px";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could make it even shorter with a ternary statement: element.style.width = element.style.width == "250px" ? "0px" : "250px";

Answer (score 0):

Using one button and the OP's functions only:

```
<a href='#' onclick=" \
    if (document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width == "250px") { \
        closeNav(); \
    } else { \
        openNav(); \
    } \
">Toggle</a>
```

This will have one button labelled toggle, and will call OP's functions when clicked. The backslashes are used to escape the end of line character

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

```js
function toggleNav() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('mySidenav');
  
  elem.setAttribute('style', (elem.clientWidth == 250) ? 'width: 0' : 'width: 250px');
}
```